# 2.4 GHz versus 434 MHz transceiver for home automation

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, rf, wireless, transmitter

I am working on a project that uses an Arduino Uno R3 and will have one receiver and one transmitter. I'm going to use this for home automation within my home in India. I want to know which transceiver would be better, a 2.4 GHz or 434 MHz module? My requirement is a 100 meter range.

Also, I would like to know if I can use an ATTiny along with the transmitter?

Comment: Data rate would also be useful as would likely obstacles between tx and rx and whether these are moving. Local contaminators of the airwaves are also a big deal. Generally speaking, in free-space the lower the frequency the further the transmission goes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Answer for ATTiny is quite clear to me. I can use ATTiny for transmitter. On one side there will be a sensor and it will transmit data using transmitter plugged to ATTiny. I am going to use this for home automation. I am located in India and trying to come up with this system for my home.

Answer (score 2):

In my (short) experience, 434MHz (or even 915MHz) would be much better getting through obstacles than 2.4GHz.

Please mind that an obstaculized 100 meter range is quite large for the usual hobbist module. Also, antenna directionality is important: if the antenna is omnidirectional you might be radiating power to directions you don't need, so take that into account for your link budget.

Answer (score 1):

I think 2.4GHz is a bit overkill. I think you could easily getaway with a 434MHz transmitter. I have used a 434MHz transmitter before with an Uno and it had a range around 100 meters and worked great.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. This helps me to decide. I will go with 434 MHz Receiver/Transmitter.